# VSCode snippets (Hypersnips) tab stops in nested use of snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am using VSCode [Hypersnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) (based off of Vi's https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), following this [guide](https://github.com/sleepymalc/VSCode-LaTeX-Inkscape) . See also [Create-Snippets-For-Ultisnips](https://aloha.org.cn/2021/03/28/Create-Snippets-for-Ultisnips/).

Consider the following example: I have a snippet

```
snippet fm "inline Math" wA
\(${1}\) $0
end snippet
```

and another snippet

```
snippet ( "parenthesis" wiA
($1) $0
end snippet
```

If I were to type `fm`, then that would produce `\(|\) |`, where the first `|` is where my cursor is, and the second `|` is where my cursor would be if I pressed `<Tab>`. Now, when I type `fm ( hi <Tab>` that produces `\((hi) |\)` as expected, but when I press `<Tab>` again (hoping to use the `$0` tab stop of the `fm` snippet), I don't get outside the right `\)` like I want, and instead a tab character (i.e. 2 spaces) are placed where the cursor is.

I am wondering if I can nest snippets like this, and still use the tab stops of the outer snippet once I exit the inner snippet.

I assume the same issue occurs if I use native VSCode snippets.

StackOverflow informs me that a similar question has been asked: [Atom - Nested snippets with tab stops error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839402/atom-nested-snippets-with-tab-stops-error), but not about VSCode's snippets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is known issue: https://github.com/draivin/hsnips/issues/78. This is a summary of the issue from Dec. 2 2021:

> So, I looked into it, the placeholder disappearance is caused by a
> workaround we are currently using to get around a VsCodeVim issue.
>
> History time:
>
> We started using the workaround to get around this issue Trigger A leaves me in visual mode, I want it to leave me in insert
> mode instead #28.
>
> Supposedly, the related issue in VSCodeVim was fixed
> here Snippet is not working Properly  VSCodeVim/Vim#5240.
>
> I'm not sure
> if it was never properly fixed, or if a regression happened, but it
> seems that the issue still exists (see Unexpectedly entered visual
> mode in snippet VSCodeVim/Vim#7068), so while that issue is still
> open, we can't remove the workaround and fix this bug.

For now, https://github.com/draivin/hsnips/issues/126 offers what I think is the best solution, namely using VSCode Neovim.